# JSTL tags print in JSP from a data class

Tags: java, html, jsp, web-applications, jstl

I have a buisness layer class to manage some data. There is a method which generate HTML-code in those code include a JSTL tag.

```
<h1 id=\"infoMsg\"><fmt:message key=\"uebersicht.infomsg\" /></h1>
```

This code will be included in JSP file
like this:

```
<%=bl.getMessages()%>
```

But in that way it will be included as HTML request, but is there another way to include the code from a method
For example like this:

```
<c:out value="${bl.getMessages()}"/>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate your question? I don't really get what you are trying to solve.

Comment: `<c:out value="${bl.messsages}"/>` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Ok. The class MessageBL is defined like `<% MessageBL bl = new MessageBL(); %>` and I want to include the HTML-Code which the h1 tag. This method return the code as String. Do I have to define `bl` in another way?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to include it in your JSP file is with the code you provided (supposing that the method is returning String with HTML format):

```
<%=bl.getMessages()%>
```

This code :

```
<c:out value="${bl.getMessages()}"/>
```

will not work because you declared your object inside a JSP scriplet like this:

```
<% MessageBL bl = new MessageBL(); %>
```

The reason is, JSP objects declared inside a scriplet are not accessible from an EL expression.

Comment: I tried it with this tag `<%=bl.getMessages()%>`
But the Problem is that the JSTL Tag `<fmt:message ...` inside the returned string won't work. How I have to declare the class to use it with JSTL? Or is this not possible?

Comment: Why the `<fmt:message...` will not work? Did you include the tag library like this: `<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>`

Comment: If I write it in the JSP it work, but if I get the source from another class and will include it, it doesn't work. Afterwards you can see the JSTL tag in the source code of the Website.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any solution. Therefore I have found a workaround:

```
<!-- set whole HTML source -->
<c:set var="message" value="${bl.messages}"></c:set>
<!-- set the key from a propertie file on a variable -->
<fmt:message key="uebersicht.infomsg" var="info"/>
<!-- get first part before the fmt tag -->
<c:set var="erst" value="${fn:substringBefore(message, '<fmt:message key')}" scope="application" />
<!-- get second part after the fmt tag -->
<c:set var="zweit" value="${fn:substringAfter(message, 'uebersicht.infomsg\" />')}" />
<!-- connect the three parts (first - key varible - second) -->
<fmt:message key="${fn:replace(erst,'?','')}"/>
${info}
<fmt:message key="${zweit}"/>
```

It works, but the two parts show question marks, the output is like this:

```
??? no information!! ???

<h1 id="infoMsg">???
no information!!
???</h1>
```

How could I replace the question marks?